# Why my Android Studio custom New Android Module template not work?

Tags: android, android-studio

i need to modify something in default New Android Module template, so from gradle-projects folder i duplicate NewAndroidModule with new name and also set a new name  in to template.xml of new module. after restarting android studio, when i clicks on File>New>NewModule, IDE show an error message with below exception:

> Duplicate key Phone & Tablet Module

can anyone help me?